# How can I select the last element of a kdb table for a set of unique column combinations?

Tags: kdb

I have this kdb table:

```
ts              ticker eid          bid     ask
--------------------------------------------------
09:30:00.001    TIF    NASDAQ       781700  792500
09:30:00.001    MRVL   BATSX        114500  118200
09:30:00.001    AVP    BATSX        239100  240100
09:30:00.001    AVP    ARCA         238000  239900
09:30:00.002    TIF    ARCA         780400  790400
09:30:00.002    AVP    BATSX        239100  239800
09:30:00.003    TIF    NYSE         783700  784000
09:30:00.003    TIF    ARCA         783400  790400
09:30:00.004    AVP    NYSE         239300  240000
09:30:00.004    TIF    NASDAQ       783500  792500
09:30:00.006    MRVL   BATSX        114500  117600
..
```

How can I select the last row of each ticker,eid pair? For this subset that would be:

```
09:30:00.001    AVP    ARCA         238000  239900
09:30:00.002    AVP    BATSX        239100  239800
09:30:00.003    TIF    NYSE         783700  784000
09:30:00.003    TIF    ARCA         783400  790400
09:30:00.004    AVP    NYSE         239300  240000
09:30:00.004    TIF    NASDAQ       783500  792500
09:30:00.006    MRVL   BATSX        114500  117600
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select without column list does this by default:

```
select by ticker,eid form t
```

Comment: True, it's also faster: \t returns 6i for this version vs. 12i for the fby version for t containing 235,400 rows (query results is 148 rows). @user1895961

Answer (score 3):

The following should be what you're looking for:

```
q)select from tbl where i=(last;i) fby ([]ticker;eid)
```

Comment: Could you explain `i=(last;i)` in english? I don't see how is `i` set.

Comment: For info on fby look [here](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/fby). i is a virtual field which indicates the index of the record. It gets a little more complicated if you want to use a partitioned table, see [here](http://code.kx.com/wiki/DotQ/DotQDotind).

Comment: Is `last` the aggregation function to `fby`, and `i` the data argument? Why the assignment to `i`?

Comment: I see, `i=` is part of the `where` condition, not an assignment. Interesting how the `where ... =` condition works with a list, not just an atomic. Shouldn't it be `where i in (...)` when using lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate over multiple fields.

```
select count i by ticker, eid from t

select last ts, last bid, last ask by ticker, eid from t
```

You will have to reorder your columns a little to exactly match your output, but thats trivial.